# retrofit 2 onResponse getting called for no internet

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

retrofit 2 onResponse() getting called even if there is no internet connection.
build.gradle:

```
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
```

Code:

```
Call<ArrayList<Repository>> call = mViewsApiEnd.getRepository("rajuse");

                call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Repository>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<Repository>> call, @NonNull Response<ArrayList<Repository>> response) {
                        if (response.code()==200) {
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Repository>> call, Throwable t) {
                        tv_response.setText("Retrofit onFailure got called :(");
                    }
```

Steps to recreate:
1.make api call when internet is present
2. turn off internet
3. make api call.
onResponse() got called

**Update:**
I found out that this is kind of umimplemented fubtionality in retrofit. Please refer my workaround and issue:

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2390

Other libraries like volley doesn't call success callback. Instead give ioexception in error callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Jake Wharton's [comment](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2390):

> You enabled HTTP caching so it's likely that the response is being served from the cache. You can check this by seeing if `cacheResponse()` is non-null on the `raw()` OkHttp response from Retrofit's `Response` object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes failure or success it should get a response

so handle it like this

```
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'


 Call<UserMaster> call = Retro.getRetroWS().UserLogin(userMaster, otp);
        try {
            Response<UserMaster> response = call.execute();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                return response.body();
            } else return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: What i have Done works fine for me, check the Edit, i just put for compile.

Comment: So lower down a version if you would like.

Comment: I've no idea about execute.. But in my enque method, Why should I get any success callback like onResponse on first place?

Comment: even isSuccesful return false I won't be able to determine whether it is noconnection case